# Use find to get all folders that don't have a .git subfolder

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

How to use find to get all folders that have not a .git folder?

On this structure::

```
$ tree -a -d -L 2
.
├── a
│   └── .git
├── b
│   ├── b1
│   └── b2
├── c
└── d
    └── .git
        ├── lkdj
        └── qsdqdf
```

This::

```
$ find . -name ".git"  -prune -o -type d -print
.
./a
./b
./b/b1
./b/b2
./c
./d
$
```

get all folders except .git

I would like to get this::

```
$ find . ...
.
./b
./b/b1
./b/b2
./c
$
```

Comment: I think that there is no way to do that "purely", but the answer below is exact.

Comment: As an aside -- note that newline-delimited lists of files aren't necessarily safe: If someone ran `mkdir -p ./$'\n'/etc/passwd`, depending on your exact version of `find` and its implementation of `-print`, you could get `/etc/passwd` in your output list. This kind of ambiguity is much of the motivation for `find -print0`, though the POSIX-compliant `find -exec` can also be used to get exact names (literal newlines, control sequences and all) out of `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inefficient (runs a bunch of subprocesses), but the following will do the job with GNU or modern BSD `find`:

```
find . -type d -exec test -d '{}/.git' ';' -prune -o -type d -print
```

If you're not guaranteed to have a `find` with any functionality not guaranteed in the POSIX standard, then you might need to take even more of an efficiency loss (to make `{}` its own token, rather than a substring, by having a shell run the test):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'test -d "$1/.git"' _ '{}' ';' -prune -o -type d -print
```

---

This works by using `-exec` as a predicate, running a test that `find` doesn't have support for built-in.

Note the use of the inefficient `-exec [...] {} [...] \;` rather than the more efficient `-exec [...] {} +`; as the latter passes multiple filenames to each invocation, it has no way to get back individual per-filename results and so always evaluates as true.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a temporary file, then:

```
find . -type d -print > all_dirs
fgrep -vxf <(grep '/\.git$' all_dirs | sed 's#/\.git$##') all_dirs | grep -vE '/\.git$|/\.git/'
rm all_dirs
```

- The first step gets all subdirectory paths into all_dirs file
- The second steps filters out the directories that have a .git subdirectory as well as the .git subdirectories.  The `-x` option is necessary because we need to eliminate only the lines that match in entirety.

This will be a little more efficient compared to [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45402423/6862601) in that it doesn't run so many subprocesses.  However, it would give a wrong output if any of the directories have a newline character in them.

Comment: Whether it's more efficient depends on how deep your trees with `.git` siblings are (and how many directories you have without them); lacking `-prune` means you're telling `find` to recurse into them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to find only the top directories add the option `-maxdepth 1` like

```
$ find . -type d -exec test -d '{}/.git' ';' -maxdepth 1 -prune -o -type d -print
.
./b
./c
$
```